# HP Officejet Pro 8710 printed page dimensions options display error

Tags: printing, libreoffice, hp

Please study the screenshot here:

[image]

The page size options are absurd. This is a recent development with this printer, although I didn't notice exactly when the problem began. I don't know whether to alert HP, or Libreoffice, or Ubuntu. Thank you.